# Given the sequence, how do I show that this series diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I currently have some trouble with this math exercise. I have to show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ with $b_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2}$ diverges.

I think I have trouble with this problem, because I'm not really sure how to apply the quotient rule or the comparison test to the given sequence.

Could anybody maybe help me out a little bit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b_n >\frac 1  {4n^{2}}+\frac 1  {4n^{2}}+...+\frac 1  {4n^{2}}$ ($n$ terms) so $b_n >\frac 1 {4n}$

Comment: Wasn't me. But I have a question to your solution. Isn't, for example, with $n=2, b_n < \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}$?

Comment: @markus Thank you. I missed a square for $2$ in the denominator.